# How do I feed my fish while I'm on vacation?

Tags: pets

I need my pet fish to be fed while I'm on vacation for a couple weeks. How can I do that without asking other people to help? I don't want to leave my fish with anyone else, and I don't want to let anyone in my house while I'm gone. It really seems like there should be some way to do this easily.

Comment: What kind of fish? Many fish types you can drop in a feeder block, which contains a bit of food, but mainly anti-acid. The fish can quite easily go a week or so without food.

Comment: Thanks, @Tetsujin. It's a betta fish. I'll look into the feeder block.

Comment: @jyoung My betta fish was fine with a feeder block for a week. (It also went without eating anything for a month one time, but that's another story.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search Amazon (or Google) "Fish Feeder Timer" there are a large number of products which will dispense food periodically - a lot of these are under $30.

Some examples -

- Here is a [14 day feeder](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000YK5W18) for $25
- Here is a [feeder which will
  work for 14-20 feeds](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01GDXGJMA) depending on what you feed.

Comment: Feeder block, pence/cents, also keeps the water clean. Automatic feeder, 25 bucks, usually dispenses too much so leaves rotting food, & no-one to clean the tank for 2 weeks. Not the best idea. When I discovered that difference, 20 years ago, my tank survival rate went from negative to positive; I actually was breeding fish [totally of their own accord, not of my design] & gaining numbers in the same tank as I'd been losing fish for years & restocking from the shop every year.

Answer (score 4):

You can buy feeding blocks that slowly dissolve in water and reaese the food over a given period of time. They are cheap and sold with names as *vacation food block*, *weekend food block* or something similar.